# HMS Site Kit - I get errors for the criteria I created by referencing the codes in the documentation

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I get errors for the criteria I created by referencing the codes in the documentation. Is there a problem on the system side? Is there any other currently receiving this error?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the errors you got please?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps depending on your location, the poi that meets the criteria you set could not be found so it may cause a criterion error. I suggest you try again in another location. You can let me know if you encounter any problems after you try.

Answer (score 0):

Without the detailed information about the errors you got, it would be hard to pinpoint where the problem is.  The easy way to referencing the HMS Site Kit integration code is to follow the HMS Site Kit Integration [Codelab](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSSiteKit/index.html#0) .

You could also download another HMS Site Kit sample code mentioned in the [document](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-sitekit-demo)  and download and install the already built APK SiteKitSampleCode-5.0.0.0.apk at [here](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-sitekit-demo/tree/master/java/app/release) .  You could run the installed SiteKitSampleCode-5.0.0.0 and test the different site search parameter combinations.  The search results varies by different locations with different data qualities.  If there is any issue with the search criteria, please post on the website and we might be able to follow up.